# Forgotten the pattern and phone not showing the "forgot pattern" button.

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, locked-out

I upgraded my Moto G2 to Android Lollipop using over-the-air upgrade. It was awesome but I set a pattern lock which I forgot. Usually after 5 wrong attempts it shows the "forgot password" button but it is not showing that button even after 100 wrong attempts. How to unlock the phone?

Comment: this may not apply to your moto, but i was able to log in to my Samsung account for my galaxy S4 with lollipop. once there, i could simply click the "unlock" button - voilá! perhaps motorola / you have a similar option?

Comment: I bet you already resolve the issue, if you did not yet, can you please tell if you use CWM or have rooted your device?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I would say I don’t think you can’t do anything about it because the forgot password button isn’t available with the Lollipop , now what you are left with is you can try unlocking your device with the help of your Google account i.e. Log yourself over the Google account you are using over Laptop/PC once done head over to the [Android device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?u=0)  and using it try unlocking your device remotely, also in order to do that your device must be connected to the Mobile  Data or Wi-Fi network. And if you don't have the access then I guess you are locked out and the only thing you can do now is factory resetting your device by holding the Power+Volume down button.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found online ...

- How to unlock your device if you have forgotten the unlock password or unlock pattern:

> If you forgot your password or unlock pattern, but still have access
>   to your Google Recovery Account, then you can just click on ‘forgot
>   password?’ and it will take you to a screen where you will be required to
>   enter your Google Account user name and password. You'll need to input
>   the same registered user name and password you use at the **Google Play
>   store**. Here is the link to the [Google
>   Accounts Recovery](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/) page.

**Source** (with plenty of steps for every type of situation): [VisiHow.com](http://visihow.com/Recover_Android_Device_in_case_of_Forgot_password/pattern_unlock_an_Android_device#How_to_unlock_your_device_if_you_don.E2.80.99t_remember_your_Google_password_recovery_account_credentials.)