# I have forgotten my phone Password

Tags: password

I have forgotten my Galaxy A7 2016 running android 5.1.1's password.
How do I open my phone without losing my files in device storage?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for you [here in this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97817/forgotten-the-pattern-and-phone-not-showing-the-forgot-pattern-button)

Quoting the answer given by @petercarlos :

> Well, I would say I don’t think you can’t do anything about it because
>   the forgot password button isn’t available with the Lollipop , now
>   what you are left with is you can try unlocking your device with the
>   help of your Google account i.e. Log yourself over the Google account
>   you are using over Laptop/PC once done head over to the Android device
>   manager and using it try unlocking your device remotely, also in order
>   to do that your device must be connected to the Mobile Data or Wi-Fi
>   network. And if you don't have the access then I guess you are locked
>   out and the only thing you can do now is factory resetting your device
>   by holding the Power+Volume down button.